# Mongodb condition with $or and $eq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use this condition to set a priority for the user_id field (with priority for the ids that I want to be a priority)

```
$cond: {
      if: {
        $or: {
          $eq: [
            "$user_id",
            ObjectId('5e9619084ad04327e4295b2c')
          ],
          $eq: [
            "$user_id",
            ObjectId('5e9618f04ad04327e4295b27')
          ]
        }
      },
      then: 1,
      else: -1
    }
}
```

but it gives me the priority of 1 only if the user id is: `5e9618f04ad04327e4295b27` (the second one in the $or condition.

what is the problem?

Comment: @mickl this is a simple document, with _id, user_id, and some Irrelevant fields I think for this question

Comment: `$or` should take an array, not an object.  Since you are constructing an object, the second field named `$eq` overwrites the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) expects an array of conditions while you're passing single object and that's why only the last condition gets applied, try:

```
{
    $cond: {
        if: {
            $or: [ 
                { $eq: ["$user_id", ObjectId('5e9619084ad04327e4295b2c') ] }, 
                { $eq: ["$user_id", ObjectId('5e9618f04ad04327e4295b27') ] }, 
            ]
        },
        then: 1,
        else: -1
    }
}
```

you can also simplify your code and use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html):

```
{
    $cond: {
        if: { $in: [ "$user_id", [ObjectId('5e9619084ad04327e4295b2c'), ObjectId('5e9618f04ad04327e4295b27')] ] },
        then: 1,
        else: -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, great! I didn't notice! and thank you for the second option, will be a better option for me